# Ubuntu 10.04 lookingfor a way to restore the taskbar shutdown applet

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, taskbar, shutdown

Can't find shutdown applet on the panel or in the dropdown box on my Ubuntu 10.04.

Currently I'm using the following command to power off my PC. `sudo poweroff`
I want to have my applet back.

Comment: I don't have enough rep. to retag or edit this. Maybe someone else can reword it?

Comment: I merged your two questions, as they were identical. Please do not post twice the same question.

Comment: Messed up your question. Hope you dont mind. >:D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the Indicator Applet back to the panel is the "right" solution, however if for some reason that doesn't work for you, this blog post describes how to create your own [shutdown, reboot & hibernate with one click](http://helpdeskgeek.com/linux-tips/shutdown-reboot-hibernate-ubuntu-quickly/) applet.

Comment: @jdouma, you're welcome :) I'm glad to be of assistance. You should *accept* the answer that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click a blank area of the panel and click "Add to panel."

Then drag the "Indicator Applet Sessions" item to the panel.

Comment: there is no shutdown applet in drop down box
of panel that what is the problem

Comment: @j douma - Did you delete some packages? Did you use the official install disc?

Comment: Indicator Applet is logout/shutdown/switch-user etc all in one. However "shutdown" and "logout" should be amoung the available applets as well. If they are missing you might try reinstalling ubuntu-desktop package